# Nodejs web scraping- How to get the contents of all args

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to create a html web scraper, and email the contents of what was found.

I am working with a music site, and am passing the names of artists through the command line, which should then access the website, searching for the html tags of song entries on the charts. The email sent should be the list of songs by that particular artist or any song they're featured on , out of the first 25 songs on the site.

My code however only emails and outputs when one argument is passed, but when more than one are entered, the contents aren't displayed in the email:

Heres a snippet of my code/jquery loop:

```js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var process = require('process');
var artists = process.argv.slice(2).toString();
var creds= require('./credentials.json');


var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(creds);

request('http://www.popvortex.com/music/charts/top-rap-songs.php', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        
        var data="";
        //var artist= $(this).children('em.artist').text();
        //var song = $(this).children('cite.title').text();
            
        $('p.title-artist').each(function(i, element) {
            var artist= $(this).children('em.artist').text();
            var song = $(this).children('cite.title').text();
            
            if(i<25 && (artist.includes(artists) || song.includes(artists))) {
                var artist= $(this).children('em.artist').text();
                var song = $(this).children('cite.title').text();
                data+=artist + ' : ' + song;
                console.log(artist + ' : '+ song);
            }
            
        })
                var mailOptions = {
                    from: creds.user,
                    to : 'jguffer4234@gmail.com',
                    subject: 'Your artists are: '  + artists.toString(),
                    text: data,
                        
                }
```

[command line input/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeZsc.png)

Email still sends, when more than one artist is entered but the songs they are included in are not.

[Latto email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqS4Y.png)

[Latto Jack email, lacking body with all of their songs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeWnZ.png)

Can anyone help? And help with my formatting of the email(line by line) would also be helpful.

Comment: Could you add the `package.json`? I'm having troubles finding some of the packages you are using, so I can recreate the issue.

Comment: Also, I think the package `request` has being deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue is in this line:

```js
if(i<25 && (artist.includes(artists) || song.includes(artists))) {
```

I think the use of the method string's `includes` is incorrect.

Instead try with:

```js
if(i<25 && (artists.includes(artist) || artists.includes(song))) {
```

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), I created an example to show how it works:

```js
let list = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log("Case 1: ", "a".includes(list)); // false
console.log("Case 2: ", list.includes("a")); // true
```

While I'm not sure if this will solve the whole issue you are having, I'm hoping it will help you out at least on that.

Comment: this helps somewhat, but only the first args songs are displayed in the email none else? Also, entries where the first arg is present in the title/song name aren't showing anymore now, "Latto & Mariah Carey: Big Energy" doesnt display anymore, only entries with only "Latto' as the artist display.

Comment: Well, there is also something else that took my attention: `var artists = process.argv.slice(2).toString();` creates a string with values separated by comas. This [link](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/) might help.

Comment: I will try to help you after work.

Comment: @manunited1of1 I added another solution, more complete. Please take a look and let me know if it did helped you out. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As promised, here is an alternative solution.

Since the `request` package has being deprecated, I'm using `axios` instead.

Please notices, that I broke the problem into small pieces.

This allowed me to provide names that describe what is being done, it make it easier to read, plus allows me to test each part as I code.

In the `package.json`, I did:

```js
{
  "name": "experiment1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10"
  }
}
```

The command line I'm using for example is:

```sh
~/Experiment1$ npm start "Jack Harlow" "Big Energy"
```

The results are:

```sh
> experiment1@1.0.0 start
> node index.js "Jack Harlow" "Big Energy"

data: {
  'Jack Harlow': 'First Class',
  'Latto & Mariah Carey': 'Big Energy (Remix) [feat. DJ Khaled]',
  Latto: 'Big Energy',
  'Lil Nas X & Jack Harlow': 'INDUSTRY BABY'
}
```

*Note: Please notices that duplicates aren't included.*

Here is the code:

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;
const url = 'http://www.popvortex.com/music/charts/top-rap-songs.php';
axios.get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    let data = findArtistAndSong(response.data);    
    console.log("data:", data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const LIST_LIMIT = 25;
function findArtistAndSong(html){
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const data = {};
  $('p.title-artist').each(function(i, element) {
    let artist= $(this).children('em.artist').text();
    let song = $(this).children('cite.title').text();            
    if (i < LIST_LIMIT && doesArtistOrSongMatch(artist, song)) {        
      data[artist] = song;
    }      
  });
  return data;
}

function doesArtistOrSongMatch(artist, song){
  return isMatch(artist) || isMatch(song);
}

const arguments = process.argv.slice(2);
const isMatch = (search) => {
  return arguments.some(item => search.includes(item));
};
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @manunited1of1, did you see this alternative complete solution I provided?